# Arduino, не работающая кнопка

Tags: arduino

недавно захотел сделать таймер со lcd1602(i2c), пьезо, потенциометром, но кнопка в основном коде не хочет работать как-будто ей мешают другие устройства, и от части так и есть я заметил что если убираю вывод режимов (if), то кнопка оживает:

```
#include "GyverButton.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#define BTN_PIN 8

uint32_t myTimer1;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);
GButton butt1(BTN_PIN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  butt1.setType(HIGH_PULL);
  butt1.setDirection(NORM_OPEN);
  butt1.setClickTimeout(400);
}
void loop() {
  //Инициализация дисплея
   lcd.init();
   lcd.backlight();
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
   // Потенциометр
   int val = analogRead(A1);
   // Вывод режимов на 1602
   butt1.tick();
   if (val>=501) {
    lcd.print("Mode: Moloko");
   } else if (butt1.isClick()) {
      Serial.println("Done!");
      Moloko(); 
   }
   if (val<500) {
    lcd.print("Mode: Water");
   } else if(butt1.isClick()) {
      Serial.println("Done!");
      Krik();
   }
}




void Kipeniye() {
  if (millis() - myTimer1 >= 120000) { 
    Krik();
  }
}


void Moloko() {
  if (millis() - myTimer1 >= 5000) {
    Krik();
    }
}

void Krik() {
  int i = 10;
  while (i--) {
    tone(12, 800);
    delay(1000);
    tone(12, 300);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Все подключено правильно проверял раз 15, нашел на другом форуме ответ, но так и не понял проблемы
Ardino IDE 1.8.13

Comment: Обьясню что выполняет код: с помощью потенциометра листают режимы, кнопкой режим подтверждают, все выводится на 1602(i2c),

Comment: Ну тут нужно знать что у вас за логика, почему проверка нажатия на кнопку каким-то образом от режима зависит. Возможно просто нужно убрать else, а оставить просто if. Скорее всего просто логика if неправильно прописана, а не "устройства мешают".

Comment: отдельная библиотека для кнопки? эх, в моё время такого не было...

Comment: Отдельную библиотеку использовал когда пытался решить проблему, не знаю почему, но подумал что заработает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поменять loop() на такой код

```
void loop() {
  //Инициализация дисплея
   lcd.init();
   lcd.backlight();
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
   // Потенциометр
   int val = analogRead(A1);
   // Вывод режимов на 1602
   butt1.tick();
   if (val>=501) {
    lcd.print("Mode: Moloko");
   } else if (val<500) {
    lcd.print("Mode: Water");
   }
   if(butt1.isClick()) {
      Serial.println("Done!");
      if (val<500) {
         Krik();
      } else {
         Moloko(); 
      }
   }
}
```

если я правильно понял задумку - то все заработает

Comment: а в сериал то зачем `Done` кидать?)

Comment: я ж хз это в базовом коде было

Comment: а косяк в логике if на лицо

Comment: done писал чтобы проверить пьезо сломался или кнопка

Comment: То что проблема в операторе if, я еще давно понял, но не пойму что не так, мне надо добавить else?

Comment: Код не помог, и я еще раз проверил пины, все правильно подключено

Comment: попробуйте убрать проверки на время (ифы) в ф-ях Kipenie и Moloko может быть в них проблема